# R Markdown prompt for parameters

Tags: r, r-markdown

I can set parameters in my .Rmd files the following way.

```
---
params:
n: 100
d: !r Sys.Date()
---
Today’s date is `r params$d`
```

But is there a way to prompt the future me (or anybody else), to *"Enter a value for n ___. Enter a date __."* with an actual prompt. I know this is possible with Shiny, but I don't want to use Shiny.

Comment: Can't you do `rmarkdown::render(..., params=list(...))`?

Comment: `rmarkdown::render(..., params='ask')` will generate a prompt when you try to knit. The prompt is made in `shiny`, but you don't have to code anything for it. If you already know about that, then what kind of prompt are you looking for?

Comment: As divibisan said, you can code the `rmarkdown::render` call, but you can also just click on `Render with parameters...` in the RStudio IDE.